# Count number of factor levels that match a character string in R

Tags: r, string-comparison, r-factor

I have a factor with several levels, and I am trying to obtain the number of levels in which the factor levels contains a given string.

Given this factor:

```
exdata <- factor(c("Test1","Test2","Sample1","Sample2","Test1","Test2","Sample3"))
```

I want to find number of levels in exdata containing "Sample" or "Test."

My solution thus far has been to use `nlevels`, `droplevels`, and `grep`:

```
nlevels(droplevels(exdata[grep("Test",exdata)]))
# Correct/intended answer is 2
nlevels(droplevels(exdata[grep("Sample",exdata)]))
# Correct/intended answer is 3
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `levels()`

```
levels(exdata)
# [1] "Sample1" "Sample2" "Sample3" "Test1"   "Test2"
```

So you can do two individual calls ...

```
length(grep("Sample", levels(exdata), fixed = TRUE))
# [1] 3
length(grep("Test", levels(exdata), fixed = TRUE))
# [1] 2
```

Or in one go ...

```
f <- function(x) length(grep(x, levels(exdata), fixed = TRUE))
sapply(c("Sample", "Test"), f)
# Sample   Test 
#      3      2
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll go with this one, rather than your comment, in the interest of readability for those on my project who are less proficient with regex :P I'll accept when the window opens.